# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when using protected route in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication, router, history, protected

I am trying to implement a protected router into my dashboard. So my landing page is directly a Login page and if the user is successfully login, I want to redirect page to my dashboard. So here is my index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/admin" component={(props) => <AdminLayout {...props} />}/>
      <Route path="" component={() => "404 NOT FOUND"} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

So my Login component is quite basic and I am fetching the data here and checking id the user exists in the database:

```
const Login = ({ submitForm }, props) => {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

  function submitForm() {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
  }
  const { handleChange, values, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm(
    submitForm,
    validate
  );

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

  const fetchLogin = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await Axios({
          //API CALL
      });
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setLogin(true);
        localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(res));
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  function loginButton() {
    fetchLogin(values.email, values.password);
    
    auth.login(() => {
      props.history.push("/admin");
    });
  }
  return (
    <form>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

So I have a basic Auth class:

```
class Auth {
    constructor() {
      this.authenticated = false;
    }
  
    login(cb) {
      this.authenticated = true;
      cb();
    }
  
    logout(cb) {
      this.authenticated = false;
      cb();
    }
  
    isAuthenticated() {
      return this.authenticated;
    }
  }
  
  export default new Auth();
```

And here is my Protected Router:

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

So everything looks fine but when I click to button submit I am getting **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined** I literally dont understand why I am getting it.

Please have a look at my code and help me.
Reviews are aldo be appreciated.

Comment: i'm not sure but have you tried `export default withRouter(Login);`?

Comment: I actually tried it for my Admin.js component and it didnt work. After you said I also tried for my Login but didnt work either

Comment: Looks to me like history is not being injected into the props, as you are only calling push on props.history.push meaning history is undefined. Can you verify that the route props are being passed into the component, specifically history?

Comment: Where do I need to pass this?

Comment: It should automatically be passed in through the Route component https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods. Can you console.log() your props in the Login component and make sure history is in it?

Comment: Hmm it comes undefined but I couldnt understand where exactly I should pass the history because in the example that I checked, it was not necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe the issue is that you are both destructuring your props and trying to use a default value.

```
const Login = ({ submitForm }, props) => {
```

can you try adding history to your destructure list or inversely only use props and not destructure the props coming into your component and then restructure later

```
const Login = ({ submitForm, history}) => { rest of your component...

or 

const Login = (props) => {
  const { submitForm, history } = props;
}
```

As the documentation says from my previous comment the props: match, location, and history, are automatically passed in when you use them in the Route